# How to change my YouTube channel name

Tags: youtube

I don't even know if it's *possible* to do this, but what I'm trying to do is to change how my name on YouTube shows up to others (when I post videos or comments or the like). I just want to change the name while keeping my channel, the videos I've posted, and suchlike.

I read (I think) that you can do this by unlinking your YouTube account to the Google+ account it's currently linked to, then link it to a different Google+ account—is this accurate? Currently it is forcing me to use my **real name** as my YouTube channel name. This is downright obnoxious; I want anonymity, I don't want every video I post to be emblazoned with my real name for every person who googles me to see! How can I change it to a username that is ***not*** my real name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to change the YouTube channel account name. Simply follow these steps:

Note: Quotes were taken from [Change your channel details - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657964).

### Change the channel Name

If your channel is connected to Google+, you can change the channel name:

> - Sign in to your channel on YouTube.
> - Open the Guide and click My Channel.
> - Point your cursor at your channel name and click the pencil icon > Channel settings.
> - Under Account Information, click Change next to your channel name.

### Change the channel ICON

> - Sign in to your channel on YouTube.
> - Open the Guide and click My Channel.
> - Point your cursor at your channel icon and click the pencil icon.

Comment: If you're going to copy verbatim from a site, even the Google Support site, you should at least link back to the source. Presenting someone else's work as your own is plagiarism. The source link for this information is: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657964

Comment: @Rakesh Raki Thank you… I _had_ been hoping to figure out a way to change _just_ my youtube account name _without_ changing my gmail address, but oh well, I guess that's not possible. Thank you too, Al E. I actually _did_ find this method with a quick google search before ever asking the question here on SE; I was hoping one of you savvy people might know some fancy technique for changing just the youtube account name without changing the gmail name, but I guess such a thing doesn't exist. Thank you both, all the same—this method _did_ work perfectly.

Comment: @AlE, I edited the answer as was suggested in [What to do when plagiarism is discovered - Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered)